# How to merge different shaped dataframes horizontally?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have three datasets of different shapes. I want to merge them horizontally. How to do that.

**Three dfs are following**

[image: data_Xception = pd.concat([data_Covid,data_Normal,data_Pneumonia],axis = 1)]

I want output as

[image]

**How to do it?**

I tried `data = pd.concat([data_Covid,data_Normal,data_Pneumonia],axis = 1)`
[image]

The format is okay but I have total 1288 values

data_Covid:- 116
data_Normal:- 317
data_Pneumonia:- 855

I am getting 855 records. How to get full 1288 values

Comment: Your expected output seems a vertical concatenation as well, but you may try removing `axis=1` from `pd.concat`.

Comment: I think this thread answers your question: [Pandas combine dataframes horizontally based on index value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67271943/pandas-combine-dataframes-horizontally-based-on-index-value)

Comment: @NuriTaş didnot work

Comment: @Vilkamini, I tried the same way, but this is not what I am looking for

Comment: So you also want them to merge vertically? I don't understand what you're trying to do, your output now contains all records, just next to each other

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557